# vba sort but not clicked

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sheet of data in table format and when I run my vba codes to sort, it sorts the data but the column filter doesn't show the downward arrow so I have to manually go back and click again. Not sure if this is something that can be implemented.

```
ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
Cells(2, dateReported).Sort key1:=Columns(dateReported), order1:=xlDescending
```

I posted the result on the left and on the right is where I have to manually click the filter to show.

[image]
[image]

Comment: are you saying that you lose the actual filter when the sort is run? Like if you filter on dates > then a certain, then run sort, then the filter is lost?

Comment: No, I didn't lose the filter, If you see the right from the left, the only difference is the long downward arrow besides the filter arrow., and not sure if there is a way to have vba display it since some of my audiences thought I didn't sort the data by glancing through it but actually the data is sorted.

Comment: So the result from vba is on the left and what i am hoping to achieve is on the right. Data is sorted correctly and no error when running the codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use [ListObject.Sort](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/listobject-sort-property-excel) to do this since your data is in a table. Something like this:

```
Sub DummySort()
    Dim myTable As ListObject
    Dim dateReported As ListColumn

    Set myTable = Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1")
    Set dateReported = myTable.ListColumns("Date Reported")

    With myTable.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add Key:=dateReported.Range, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
            Order:=xlDescending
        .Header = xlYes
        .Orientation = xlSortColumns
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your input but I am getting an error of out of script when I am trying to declare mytable. I do have my data in sheet1 and table named Table1 as provided by your codes.

Comment: Is that a "Subscript out of range` error? If you go to Formulas > Name Manager - do you see "Table1" on Sheet1? Is the error on `Set myTable...` or another line?

Comment: Hi yes it was a Subscript out of range and I double checked it and my data is in sheet1 and in Table1 as exactly defined like how you have.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error - is the sheet named exactly "Sheet1"? And you're sure that the error is on `Set myTable`? Has the data been copied from another table - i.e. the formatting might look like it's a table but it's not actually one?